# Split exact sequence and reflexive tensor product.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, tensor-products, exact-sequence, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $T \in \mathbb{B}(X)$ is Fredholm operator (I.e the range of $T$ is closed, the ker of $T$  has a finite dimension and the dimension of the co-kernel ($X/ R(T)$) of $T$ is finite ).
Clearly, 
$$0 \rightarrow \ker(T) \rightarrow  X \rightarrow T(X) \rightarrow  0 $$ is a split exact sequence.
I have the following questions:        \
1-  Let $H$ be a reflexive Banach space. Is the following sequence 
$$ 0 \rightarrow \ker(T) \widehat{\otimes } H \rightarrow  X \widehat{\otimes } H \rightarrow T(X)\widehat{\otimes } H \rightarrow  0$$ an exact sequence ?. Where  $X \widehat{\otimes }H$ denotes the topological tensor product completed with respect to the greatest crossnorm of Schatten.\
2-  $\ker(T) \widehat{\otimes } H$ is it reflexive ?.
Please, I want explanatory answers to the previous questions.
Thanks.